# How to analyze oracle dump file

Tags: oracle, impdp

I need to analyze a large Oracle DMP file. So far, I have no experience with Oracle.

I know that the database contains information about certain people, for example a person with the name Smith.
I don't know how the database is structured (which table contains which information, are there triggers, ...).

As long as I don't know which tables I have to search, the best way I have found to work with the database files is to use grep.
This way, I can at least verify that the database really does contain the name "Smith".
Ultimately, I would like to have an SQL dump that can be viewed, filtered and understood in a text editor.

The DMP file was created with

```
expdp system / [PW] directory = [expdp_dir] dumpfile = [dumpfile.dmp] full = yes logfile = [logfile.log] reuse_dumpfiles = y
```

I know that the name Smith occurs often in the Database. Running `grep -ai smith dumpfile.dmp` returns many hits.

To analyze the database further I installed oracle-database and sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-x64. I imported the DMP file with

```
impdp USERID = system / [PW] FULL = y FILE = [dumpfile.dmp]
```

The folder `C:\app\[user]\oradata\orcl` now contains the files `SYSAUX01.DBF` and `SYSTEM01.DBF`, among others.
I suspect that these are the database files.

The command `grep -ai smith * .DBF` does *not* return any hits.
Either the files `SYSAUX01.DBF` and `SYSTEM01.DBF` are not the databases or something did not work on the import.

Using the SQL developer, I log in with the following data:

User: system
Password: [PW] (= PW from the `expdp` command)
SDI: orcl

In SQL developer, I do not find Smith. SQL developer displays many tables, most of which seem
to be empty and none of which I understand. I suspect that these tables are not the tables I am looking for. Perhaps I need to log in a different way (different user, different SDI?).

I tried to export the database to an SQL dump file, trying out various options that SQL developer provides,
but the result does not contain the string "Smith".

Something is not right:

1. Import is faulty
2. wrong SDI
3. Export is faulty
4. anything else

What might have gone wrong along the way?

Comment: What was the output from your impdp command? What version of Oracle are you using, and what version of Oracle generated the dump file?

Comment: What went wrong along the way is your fundamental mis-understanding of how databases work.  Yes, those .dbf files are part of the database. But only part.  And even if you did find 'smith' by grepping the data file that actually contains it, what then?  You get data from databases by issuing sql queries, not by grepping the raw data files.  The relationship and structure of the data files is far more complex than that.

Comment: What exactly do you think `smith` is? A schema, a schema object (table, package, procedure), or data with a table? If a schema or schema object try using `SQLFILE=` option to get `impdp` to just write out the DDL commands. If data, there is the `CONTENT=` but you'll have to research exactly what that does. Failing that try running the dmp file through the bash `strings` command and then `grep` the output.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, another issue of trying to read the `.DBF` files is that recent versions of Oracle allow all sorts of compression algorithms, making it impossible to get any matches.  Also, if the encryption option is enabled, the data in the files are... encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot misconceptions in your question.

- Oracle Datapump is a database utility designed for exporting and importing. But the content, either is DDL commands ( as create table, create index ) or data from the tables, is stored as binary, so you can't check the contents of those files. There are options to extract the DDL commands from the dumpfile and put it into a script.
- The datafiles you are mentioned are part of the database itself, they have nothing to do with datapump. **Do not touch those files**
- I don't know what you mean by "Smith" , if you mean an schema, after importing make a select over dba_users looking for the field username = 'SMITH'
- If you mean looking for "Smith" as part of any of those tables, you will have to look in any single table of the database ( except the ones of schemas belonging to Oracle ) and for each field that is a string
- SDI does not mean anything. I guess you meant SID or Oracle System ID, an unique identifier to identify a database in a specific environment

There is nothing wrong. The problem I believe is that you don't exactly know what you are looking for.

Check this

A user/schema with name SMITH

```
SQL> SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'SMITH' ;
```

A table which name contains the word SMITH ( unlikely )

```
SQL> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%SMITH%' ;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should run impdb with the SQLFILE=<filename> parameter and analyze that for what the dump file is trying to create. Should give more insight into what you are looking for. Check DATA PUMP documentation here for argument details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/img_text/impfileopts.html